# able to read one file but failed to read multiple json files from a folder into a padas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a folder that has many jason files, say folder is "myfolder" and files are:
data1.json, data2.json, data3.json.... and so forth.

There are total 6 key names and these jason files all have same key names, say: col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, and col6 (i.e. the columns of df when these are converted into dataframe)

I want to read all these files into one pandas (or any other dataframe).

What I am doing is:

```
os.chdir("D:/myfolder/")
with open(json_files[0], encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())


df = json.loads(open('data1.json').read())

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(df)
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.split(".")[-1])
```

And I got DF for one file, but I am not sure how I can read all the files in loop and append `df` ? I tried for loop but could not do it.

Is there a way out?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of dataframes via a `for` loop. Then use `pd.concat` to combine in a final step.

It's not advisable to continually append to an existing dataframe, as `pd.DataFrame.append` is expensive relative to `list.append` and a single `pd.concat` call.

```
dfs = []

for file in json_files:
    df = json.loads(open(file).read())
    df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(df)
    df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.split('.')[-1])
    dfs.append(df)

df_full = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping.. but it threw an error:   
      3 for file in json_files:
      4     df = json.loads(open(file).read())
----> 5     df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(df)
      6     df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.split('.')[-1])
      7     dfs.append(df)



AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: I suggest you test for one `json` file at a time, e.g. `json_files = ['file.json']` and see if it works for a few files in isolation. If it does, then it seems something is wrong with your data.

Comment: errors... `dfs = []
for file in json_files:
    print(file)
    df = json.loads(open(file).read())

#     df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(df)
#     df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.split('.')[-1])
#     dfs.append(df)

​

df_full = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)

data1.json
data2.json
data3.json
data4.json
data5.json
data6.json
data7.json
data8.json
data9.json

      8 #     dfs.append(df)
      9 
---> 10 df_full = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: First thing I notice is that you have `pd.concat(df...)`. You have to apply `concat` on the list `dfs`..